# C++ makefile does not compile

Tags: c++, makefile

Apologies for such a beginner question, but I have been stuck on making Makefile work on my c++ files for quite a while

My makefile contains two .cpp files and one .h files and are as follows

```
example.o: example.cpp example.h
    g++ -c example.cpp

main.o: main.cpp example.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

main: main.o example.o
    g++ main.o example.o -o main
```

and it outputs the following error when I try to *make main*

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: *(with large pieces of code)*
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

However, it works perfectly fine when I just do a compilation of the program by using

```
g++ main.cpp example.cpp -o main
```

Is there any reason why Makefile doesn't work but just compiling works? Thanks a lot for any replies!

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems. What is the output of `make main --trace`? What symbols are reported as undefined?

Comment: When you run `make` with no parameters, it will build the first thing in your Makefile, so you probably want to move the rule for `main` to be at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show the output of make including the compiler lines that were invoked, not just some of the error output.  Also it would be helpful if you provided at least *SOME* of the symbols that were not found so we could get an idea of what is missing.

There is no reason from the info you've provided why this should happen, so the cause must be related to some detail that you *haven't* provided.

One difference between the command line and the makefile is that the makefile builds object files then turns them into an executable, while the command line simply compiles the sources directly into an executable.

Maybe you have some `.o` files lying around from a different compilation?  If you use `rm -f *.o` before you run `make` do you still see the same errors?

Also, it's a little odd that you're invoking `g++` but the error output says `clang` which is a completely different compiler.  Are you trying to build on MacOS?  You should always provide your operating system info.  If you're building on MacOS you should just use `clang` directly, unless you've explicitly install GCC and want to use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! And yes I am using MacOS to build it. I've solved the problem and turns out that I was using plain text rather than TextEdit to type the Makefile xd sorry

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, but there's no way that "using plain text ... to type the Makefile" would cause an error like that, by itself.  There's nothing wrong with using plain text to create a makefile (as long as you get the TAB vs spaces right, and if you didn't you'd get a make syntax error not a linker error).